# How can I include HTML in an XML document?

Tags: html, xml

I am trying to insert some HTMl into an XML document, but its not working. I am trying to add it in the  tag.

Any ideas how I can do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<your_card>
    <your_message>
    my message here
    </your_message>
</your_card>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “not working”? Be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the HTML in [CDATA tags (*character data*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) to indicate raw, uninterpreted/unparsed text.

```
<![CDATA[your markup]]>
```

> The term indicates that a certain portion of the document is general character data, rather than non-character data or character data with a more specific, limited structure. ... In an XML document or external parsed entity, a CDATA section is a section of element content that is marked for the parser to interpret as only character data, not markup.

Comment: Thanks, but the markup doesn't show up.
<your_message>
 <![CDATA[<b>test</b>]]>
 </your_message>

Comment: The markup isn't meant to show up, it's meant to be _stored_: displaying/rendering it is a completely different thing/question; XML is a storage format, how you display it is up to you.